# how to handle the ajax response data in one place before the other handlers in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

how to handle the ajax response data in one place before the other handlers

In my web application,I use a lot of $.ajax method to send request to the server and get the response data,and I also use some jQuery plugin like jsTree,datatables etc.(I use these plugin's ajax data source),

and the app have a permission control system, so if the user haven't login in, the ajax request will get some json reponse data like {havePermission:"no",permisisonName:"PERMISSION_NAME"},so I want to find a place to handle the ajax respone data before all the other handlers.I have tried the .ajaxComplete,.ajaxError,.ajaxSuccess,even extend the $.ajax method, but It all doesn't works.

so is there some place to achieve this goal?

Comment: let your server status along with with json data. In your success check the status of response , if this is other than 200 do whatever you want.

Comment: thank you. but because use of jQuery plugin(jsTree, datatables),so do like this cann't achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

You such scenarios you can create a base class for all http handlers where you can override ProcessRequest method to do some user validation stuff.

Thus any of you httpHandler's process request will first call base.processrequest and then continue with its own business logic.

In the base class processRequest, if the validation does not passes, you can write the response there only.

Thanks

Pranav Kaushik

Comment: the problem now is in the client. is there any undocumented ajax event handler in the jQuery $.ajax method?

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me if I have understood you incorrectly.

Hoping that you want a generic place on client side where all the requests that are going to server and all the response that are coming from server can be trapped and validated. Right?

If that is the case, here is a way using AJAX

write your own wrapper over AJAX call something like this

function doAJAX(reasonToCallServer, url, processData, data, isAync, contentType, callbackmethod){
**ValidateRequest(reasonToCallServer, data);**
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   processData: false,
   data: data,
   **success: function(response){ValidateResponse(reasonToCallServer, contentType, response, callbackmethod)**
}});
}

Now you can define your ValidateRequest and ValidateResponse methods and do whatever generic validations you want to do.

Notice in ValidateResponse you have recieved the callbackMethod parameter, which is the actual method to be called when all validations are done.

And ResonToCallServer is nothing but a string for the context in which you are calling the server. Thus you can do a switch over this and do your context specific validations too.

Feel free to ask for further clarifications. And vote if you feel this helps :)

Thanks,
Pranav Kaushik

Comment: thanks a again.your idea is great. and because of i use jquery plugins like jsTree,datatables, and they are seems to use $.ajax method to get async data, so I just want to find a simple way like hack $.ajax method or some globle event handler, but according to many articles and faqs that I found on the internet these days, there isn't a simpe way to achieve my goal. so I must think another way.  and thank you very much

Comment: If you liked it, a vote will be serve the appreciation for me :)